Powershell get-service -Status property issue
Under powershell >= 5.1
I get:
PS C:\> get-service -Status Running
Get-Service: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Status'

But the property does exist anyway ?
PS C:\> get-service | Get-Member


Get-Service does not know -Status

For an answer to your question see: https://superuser.com/questions/144960/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-windows-services-and-their-status-to-a-text-file
